# GCP PubSub Spring Integration using subscribeAndConvert auto_ack config

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

so creating a subscriber using

```
pubSubTemplate.subscribeAndConvert( subs, { message ->
...
```

is very concise.

Is it possible though, to set the Ack Mode using this approach to creating subscribers?

Using channel adapters (which are less concise imo, and reason why ia am exploring subscribeAndConvert option), as described here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring#receiving-messages-using-channel-adapters - i can do it, e.g.

```
adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
```

There is a config available with spring cloud stream for this;

```
 spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.ack-mode: AUTO_ACK
```

Thanks!

Comment: To automatically acknowledge messages when pulling from a Subscription, you can use the `--auto-ack` flag on [gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/pubsub/subscriptions/ack). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Thanks @PrajnaRaiT - my goal is to use pubSubTemplate.subscribeAndConvert - so i dont need to explicitly pull as this method takes care of it. What is also driving my question, is there is a config available with spring cloud stream for this;  
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      gcp:
        pubsub:
          default:
            consumer:
              ack-mode: AUTO_ACK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `pubSubSubscriberTemplate.subscribeAndConvert` there is no parameter to set **AckMode(AckMode.AUTO)**.

In Spring Integration, you can configure bind an input channel to a Pub/Sub Subscription using the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.

As you have mentioned using [PubSubInboundChannelAdapter](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/messaging/pubsub#inbound-channel) you can set acknowledgement mode to auto using the syntax `adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO)`.

**Example code:**

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel orderRequestInputChannel() {
  return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter orderRequestChannelAdapter(
    @Qualifier("orderRequestInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
    PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
  PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
      new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(
          pubSubTemplate, "orders-subscription");
  adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
  adapter.setPayloadType(Order.class);
  adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO);

  return adapter;
}
```

You can set the ACK mode of the [consumer endpoint](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/) in application.properties as:

`spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.bindings.{CONSUMER_NAME}.consumer.ack-mode=AUTO_ACK`